# indexes are not cached in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

the task is to cache queries before the update index, which also sometimes changes
queries of the form sandbox6.dev.com/api/v2/qa/diff/2291314/a49ef19f-60 ...
2291314 - update index
also index may be 2291378768 or 22913176
how to write a cache for nginx correctly if you need to cache all requests with a response of 200, and not cache the rest, but just send a non-backend? why is nothing cached with such a config

```
server {
listen              80;
server_name          sandbox6.dev.com;

 location / {
        return 403 ;
           }
 location ~ ^/api/v2/qa/diff/[0-9]+/(?<cache_key>.+) {
      resolver 10.73.0.41;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      client_max_body_size 20m;

      rewrite "^/api/v2/qa/diff/(.*)" /api/push/diff/$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://test.qa.com;

     add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

     proxy_cache one;
     proxy_cache_valid 200 2h;
     proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$cache_key$is_args$args;

  }
```

I've tried different implementations, I can't understand why this is happening?